# How to set the Dojox Datagrid row height to a single line

Tags: datagrid, dojo, row-height

I'm trying to fix the height of a Dojox 1.3 Datagrid to a single line (like Excel). The current functionality is to automatically increase the row's height when more data than will fit into a single line is available.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this? It seems like it should be built in functionality for a datagrid, conisidering that this is the default behavior for spreadsheets.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Currently, there's no way to resize a single row in the DataGrid.

Comment: see jfkelley's answer, the one and only way is to style your way through it. Perhaps derive your own grid class with the mentioned functionality to traverse the table cells (use dojo.query after .render()), if the grid object itself has this functionality built in you can easily make a 'collapse/expand' button

Answer (score 1):

I think you can.

Here is what I've been experimenting with:
In class .dojoxGridCellContent, add:

white-space:nowrap;
overflow:hidden;

For my "Squeeze/Expand" functions, I use a little function to dynamically change a class attribute and then I re-paint the grid.

I'm a firm believer in the need to be able to crunch rows (both in Excel and in html) down to 1 "row" high in order to facilitate vertical visual scanning (truncating cell contents as necessary) and then to be able to expand them out again to see the full contents in a cell on any particular row.

Manually sizing the column to be wide enough to fit all the possible text in any given cell is a terrible solution if you have variable amounts of text in any given cell.  For productivity apps, non-functional white space is the enemy.

I wish there were a way built in to Dojo to do this useful thing (also solving the perennial cross-browser conditional ellipses thing).

Comment: Actually, to get it to win the CSS specificity rules, I set ".claro .dojoxGridContent", not just ".dojoxGridContent".  There may be a way to dictate style of the dojoxGridContent div when setting up the grid, but I don't know what that is (yet).  Otherwise, works great!

Comment: Ok, here it is.  Just before rendering the grid, I walk the layout structure and set cellStyles="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;height:1em".  Adding the height allows you to squeeze even if there are br objects in the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Found a hack!

use this as the column formatter:

```
function(obj){
    return "<div style='height:15px;text-overflow:ellipsis'>"+obj+"</div>"
}
```

This is just a hack and I'm seeing some problem with the row selector. But anyway, hope this help you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the height, but you can adjust the width.  If you have a good idea how wide your cell will normally need to be in order to fit the string on one line you can set it in your < th > element to maximize the number of rows that fit onto one line.

```
<table  //dojo grid properties>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="90px" field="fieldName" ...>
                Field Name
            </th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.